# Unque numbering rows in SQl Server for duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to re-write this query to restart numbering when the UName changes so that my result set is:

1 FerrieC
2 FerrieC
3 FerrieC
1 GrayD
1 TimneyA
2 TimneyA

> SELECT    Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY
>   u.UName) as RowNumber ,   u.UName FROM (
>   SELECT    'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL
>   SELECT    'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL
>   SELECT    'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL
>   SELECT    'TimneyA' As UName UNION ALL
>   SELECT    'TimneyA' As UName UNION ALL
>   SELECT    'GrayD' As UName ) as u

Thansk! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT   Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY UName ORDER BY u.UName) as RowNumber 
         ,u.UName 
FROM  (  SELECT 'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Ferriec' As UName UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'TimneyA' As UName UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'TimneyA' As UName UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'GrayD' As UName ) as u
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  For some crazy reason I thought the partition clause had to do with physical partitions!

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY u.UName) - RANK OVER (ORDER BY u.UName) + 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: This will work as well, but the answer below had been incoroprated in my own problem query.